# Django : Filter and edit model_set of object and return query set of that object in one to many relation

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, one-to-many, django-filter

Suppose that I have two models that there is one-to-many relationship between them. These are my models:

> 1. Exam
> 2. Question

I want to get a `QuerySet` of related questions of exam objects that have  texts which contains `q1_text`. And also I want to filter my `question_set` of these exam objects that only contain `q1_text`.

These are my `Exam` and `Question` models:

## models.py

```
class Exam(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=400, default='how are you?')
    exam = models.ForeignKey(Exam, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Suppose that in returned `QuerySet` exist question objects that some of them have text field with value of `q1_text` and others with value `q2_text`. ***For this purpose I did use this filter:***

```
Exam.objects.filter(question__text__icontains='q1_text')
```

If I use this code I get `QuerySet` of exam objects but there is some questions with text `q2_text` in `question_set` of these objects.However, I want just questions that contains `q1_text` so It's not correct result for me.

I need to filter `question_set` of `exam objects` too. so I used this code:

**second filter**

```
Exam.objects.filter(question__text__icontains='q1_text')[i].question_set.all().filter(text__icontains='q1_text')
```

But the problem is that the output of this code is `QuerySet` of `Question model` but I want `QuerySet` of `Exam model` with edited `question_set` that contains only questions that their `text` contains `q1_text`

**My Suggestions :**

> Maybe one possible way is to use **second filter** and then set the
>   attribute `question_set` of `exam objects` to the output of it but I don't know
>   how to do it in code.
>
> In general I think we should find a way to edit or filter `question_set`
>   of `exam objects` and get QuerySet of these exam objects in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Tack it easy and enjoy working with `Django ORM`!

1. first of all, add `related_name` (read more: [1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects), [2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)) to your `exam` field in `Question` model.

```py
exam = models.Foreign‍‍‍‍Key(Exam, related_name='question_exams', on_delete=models.CASCADE)‍‍‍‍‍‍
```

2. Finally, for setting your conditions in `filter` method use `Q` object (read more: [1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects), [2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects) ,[3](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/query_relatedtool.html)). try this query:

```py
    from django.db.models import Q
    q_object = Q(
        Q(question_exams__exam = your_current_exam) and Q(question_exams__text__contains='q1_text')
    )
    final_result = Exam.objects.filter(q_object)
```

Hope I can help you.